# DataGridView Column Enumerations

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms

I have a DataGridView (lets call it `dGrid`) with four columns. One of them is the type (`dGrid.TypeColumn`) column.

The values used to fill this type column will come from a database. The logic to get the value is complete and testing, but for it to work, I need to be able to name the control in the database. For example, to get the value of the `dGrid.TypeColumn` column label, I need to add `dGrid.TypeColumn` as a row value in the database.

Would I be able to set a value in the database that could refer to the  `dGrid.TypeColumn` column at row 1, 2, or 3? It looks like calling `dGrid.TypeColumn[0]` is not the correct format. `dGrid.TypeColumn1` also does not work.

**How can I call enumerations of a column in a DataGridView?**

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
var val = dGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
```

where `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index of the `TypeColumn` column.